# Como faço para excluir parte de uma string em um pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tenho um DataFrame com a coluna `Assinatura.Cadastro`, porém a data e hora está tudo junto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso deixar somente o campo de horas, excluindo a data ?

Comment: Thiago, editei sua pergunta para facilitar a busca de outros com o mesmo problema, se achar que eu mudei muito o sentido você pode [edit] ou se quiser pode voltar para uma versão anterior acessando [revisões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/492934/revisions)

Comment: Perfeito, sem problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o dado me parece uma string, voce pode utiliza o metodo [`slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html)

```
df['hora'] = df['coluna'].str.slice(10)
# ou usando índices ↓
# df['hora'] = df['coluna'].str[10]

df['data'] = df['coluna'].str.slice(0,10)
# ou usando índices ↓
# df['data'] = df['coluna'].str[0:10]
```

<sup>Veja o codigo funcionado no [ideone](https://ideone.com/NiUr5m)</sup>

Como você quer substituir você pode simplesmente colocar:

```
df['Assinatura.Cadastro'] = df['Assinatura.Cadastro'].str.slice(0,10)
# ou usando índices ↓
# df['Assinatura.Cadastro'] = df['Assinatura.Cadastro'].str[0:10]
```

Comment: Se não for um problema você pode transformar em String, `df['coluna'].astype(str).str.slice(0,10)` o `.astype(str)` transforma em string

Comment: agora consegui, muito obrigado pela ajuda.